# Usage of Like or As

Tags: as-like

Are these sentences synonymous?

(1) "I treat him like an animal."
 = "I treat him as an animal would."

(2) "I treat him as an animal."  = "I treat him as if he were an animal."

Also, can (1) or (2) have more than one meaning?

Comment: “I treat him like an animal” more typically means that I treat him the way I would treat an animal.